# Recursion In simple ML Standard

Tags: functional-programming, ml

```
fun max (xs : int list)=
    if null xs
    then NONE 
    else
    let val tl_ans = max(tl xs)
    in
        if isSome tl_ans andalso valOf tl_ans > hd xs
        then
        tl_ans
        else
        SOME (hd xs)
    end
```

I can't figure how this program works from my understanding:
we enter the else then we call max(tl xs) recursively till it hit none so when we have none we check the if in the in and it will be false then we return SOME(hd xs).
the question will be that I can't understand how this program works line by line I feel that I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the mistake you're making is trying to reason about several recursions at once.
Focus at just one function call at a time.

Example:

`max []` is `NONE`, as you say.

Next, take `max [2]` as an example.

This is

```
let val tl_ans = max []
in
    if isSome tl_ans andalso valOf tl_ans > 2
    then
        tl_ans
    else
        SOME 2
end
```

which is

```
if isSome NONE andalso valOf NONE > 2
then
    NONE
else
    SOME 2
```

which is clearly `SOME 2`.

Next, try `max [3,2]`

This is

```
let val tl_ans = max [2]
in
    if isSome tl_ans andalso valOf tl_ans > 3
    then
        tl_ans
    else
        SOME 3
end
```

and you know that `max [2]` is `SOME 2`, so this is

```
if isSome (SOME 2) andalso valOf (SOME 2) > 3
then
    SOME 2
else
    SOME 3
```

which is `SOME 3`.

And so on...